# Getting a percentage from MySql with a group by condition, and precision

Tags: mysql, group-by

I was about to ask the MySql list this and remembered about SO.

Running MySql 5.0.85, I need to be as efficient as possible about a few queries.  If I could get a little review, I would appreciate it.

I collect data in the millions, and need the top 50 grouped by one field, with a percentage of how much those top 50 occupy.

Here is what I have come up with...
1) I have a feeling I can be more efficient, perhaps with a join
2) How can I get the percentage to be of precision in the hundredths, so * 100.00
    ie: .07 becomes 7.00, getting SQL errors if I (percentage * 100)

```
SELECT user_agent_parsed, user_agent_original, COUNT( user_agent_parsed ) AS thecount, 
    COUNT( * ) / ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM agents ) AS percentage
FROM agents
GROUP BY user_agent_parsed
ORDER BY thecount DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Second issue, once a day I need to archive the result of the above.  Any suggestions on how to best to do that?  I can schedule with cron, or in my case, launchd, unless someone has a better suggestion.

Would you think that a simple 'SELECT (the above) INTO foo' would suffice?

Comment: Second Issue: dont you need the time/date in the archive?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have a timestamp of added and updated, just did not show it in the example. I am going to carry a unique id as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First Issue:

```
select count(*) from agents into @AgentCount;

SELECT user_agent_parsed
     , user_agent_original
     , COUNT( user_agent_parsed )  AS thecount
     , COUNT( * ) / ( @AgentCount) AS percentage
 FROM agents
GROUP BY user_agent_parsed
ORDER BY thecount DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: How is that a higher performer? Still two queries, you may even slow it down as you are now literally storing a variable.  milliseconds sure, but can you elaborate?

Comment: Your nested query is potentially run once per grouped element. Mine runs once. Granted, this might be caught by the optimizer..

Comment: No need for the dual selects, the MySql optimizer, at least in 5.x takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I quite don't understand your question fully so I'll just answer first your question on how to get the percentage. And I'll use your present query.

```
 SELECT user_agent_parsed, user_agent_original, COUNT( user_agent_parsed ) AS thecount, 
    ((COUNT( * ) / ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM agents)) * 100 ) AS percentage
FROM agents
GROUP BY user_agent_parsed
ORDER BY thecount DESC LIMIT 50;
```

In order for me to help you further, I think I need you to elaborate it further ;-)

Comment: Misplaced paren, Thanks!.  The second issue is that I will take the result of the above query, and want to save that results state in time.  I am storing hits to a user agent log, so I can find that Safari is 100 uses a day, IE is 65 uses a day, etc (simplified).  This of course changes from day to day and I want to chart the growth/decline over a year.  I need to store the result of the above query, for long term stats.  I am considering selecting the result into a new table, unless that is a bad idea and there is a more elegant one,