# Getting percentage of "Count(*)" to the number of all items in "GROUP BY"

Tags: mysql

Let's say I need to have the **ratio** of "number of items available from certain category" to "the number of all items". Please consider a MySQL table like this:

```
/*

mysql> select * from Item;
+----+------------+----------+
| ID | Department | Category |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | Popular    | Rock     |
|  2 | Classical  | Opera    |
|  3 | Popular    | Jazz     |
|  4 | Classical  | Dance    |
|  5 | Classical  | General  |
|  6 | Classical  | Vocal    |
|  7 | Popular    | Blues    |
|  8 | Popular    | Jazz     |
|  9 | Popular    | Country  |
| 10 | Popular    | New Age  |
| 11 | Popular    | New Age  |
| 12 | Classical  | General  |
| 13 | Classical  | Dance    |
| 14 | Classical  | Opera    |
| 15 | Popular    | Blues    |
| 16 | Popular    | Blues    |
+----+------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Total
    -> FROM Item
    -> WHERE Department='Popular'
    -> GROUP BY Category;
+----------+-------+
| Category | Total |
+----------+-------+
| Blues    |     3 |
| Country  |     1 |
| Jazz     |     2 |
| New Age  |     2 |
| Rock     |     1 |
+----------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

*/
```

What I need is basically a result set resembles this one:

```
/*
+----------+-------+-----------------------------+
| Category | Total | percentage to the all items | (Note that number of all available items is "9")
+----------+-------+-----------------------------+
| Blues    |     3 |                          33 | (3/9)*100
| Country  |     1 |                          11 | (1/9)*100
| Jazz     |     2 |                          22 | (2/9)*100
| New Age  |     2 |                          22 | (2/9)*100
| Rock     |     1 |                          11 | (1/9)*100
+----------+-------+-----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

*/
```

How can I achieve such a result set in a **single query**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in a query, but why not do it in the code that handles the result?

Comment: unfortunately, I need to make it in one single query to fit in my API. nevertheless, I found a similar Q&A at stackoverflow. See my answer below.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Total , (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE Department='Popular')) * 100 AS 'Percentage to all items', 
FROM Item
WHERE Department='Popular'
GROUP BY Category;
```

I'm not sure of the MySql syntax, but you can use a sub-query as shown.

Comment: Yes you are right, I also found this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576370/getting-a-percentage-from-mysql-with-a-group-by-condition-and-precision

It seems like the inner query might not even take so much time even though it is repeated, thanks to MySQL optimization etc.

Comment: Isn't the division supposed to be reversed in order to get a percentage?

`((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE Department='Popular') / COUNT(*)) * 100`

Answer (score 12):

This should do it:

```
SELECT I.category AS category, COUNT(*) AS items, COUNT(*) / T.total * 100 AS percent
FROM Item as I,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Item WHERE Department='Popular') AS T
WHERE Department='Popular'
GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: You were missing a comma in the FROM clause, and there was no column alias for the `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 5):

```
SET @total=0;

SELECT Category, count(*) as Count, count(*) / @total * 100 AS Percent FROM (
    SELECT Category, @total := @total + 1
    FROM Item
    WHERE Department='Popular') temp
GROUP BY Category;
```

An advantage of doing it this way is you do not have to duplicate the `WHERE` condition, which is a ticking time bomb the next time someone comes by to update the condition, but doesn't realize it's in two different places.

Avoiding the duplicate `WHERE` condition also improves readability, *especially* if your `WHERE` is more complex (with multiple joins, etc).

Comment: Inline variable assignment (:=) is deprecated in Mysql 8 and will be removed