# sql query to calculate percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table below, i need to find the percentage of males who are in the state 'nyc'.

```
  select count(*) from table where state = 'nyc' and gender = 'male';
```

gives me the count of males from nyc. I need the % of males from nyc as 75%.

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| name  | state | gender |
+-------+-------+--------+
| Jon   | nyc   | male   |
+-------+-------+--------+
| obama | LA    | male   |
+-------+-------+--------+
| kat   | nyc   | male   |
+-------+-------+--------+
| andy  | nyc   | male   |
+-------+-------+--------+
| sri   | nyc   | female |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

desired output:

state, male_percentage--> nyc, 75 %

as 3 are males and 1 is female from total 4 from nyc.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Any queries that you built yourself that might fail/produce undesired output? Probably COUNT might help you here somehow?

Comment: why do this in SQL, why not post process this information in PHP ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting percentage of "Count(\*)" to the number of all items in "GROUP BY"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061655/getting-percentage-of-count-to-the-number-of-all-items-in-group-by)

Comment: LA (the city) is not a state - although of course Louisiana is!! NYC is not a state either, unless you're thinking 'empire state of mind')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one select from table )

```
 select state ,100 * sum( IF(gender = 'male',1,0) ) / count(*) 
    from table where state = 'nyc' 
    group by state
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)/(select count(*) from table where gender='male')*100
from table where state = 'nyc' and gender = 'male';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with subquery:

```
(select count(*) from table where gender='male' and state = 'nyc')/
(select count(*) from table where state = 'nyc') *100;
```

but it can be easyer and more advisable IMHO to do it in PHP

Comment: Select data from DB better to do with sql queries, not with PHP

Comment: @ViktorBardakov I was not speaking about SELECTING but about doing calculations that is more flexible with PHP compared to SQL. Anyway this is just my opinion as I said in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select count(*) from table where state='nyc' and gender='male') * 100.0 / count(*)
from table
```

is about the simplest way.

*works in sqlite3*