# SQL Query percentage of a column

Tags: sql

how to query percentage of students attendance in table below

```
Name    Attendance
A   1
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
```

Comment: can i plz have the reason of down vote to prevent in future question  the mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061655/getting-percentage-of-count-to-the-number-of-all-items-in-group-by . I think your question has been already resolve in this

Comment: I think it is not easy to know what the table means. There is no date information. How should I interpret this? How are the rows updated? Isn't the table with many columns for different days and with fixed number of names better for your purpose?

Comment: select sum(Attendance = 0) / sum(Attendance = 1) * 100 from students

Comment: something like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest `Sum(Attendance) / Count(Attendance)` as a percentage:

```
  select Name,
         Sum(Attendance) / Count(Attendance) * 100 as Percentage
    from MyTable
group by Name
```

So, in case of `A` student we have `Sum(Attendance) == 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 1` and `Count(Attemdance) == 4` and the percentage is `1 / 4 * 100 = 25`